# Visual Basic Form doesn't dispose all items when asked to

Tags: vb.net, winforms, garbage-collection, dispose

hope someone can help..

I'm writing a little Windows application with VB.NET forms,

I've created a subroutine which disposes all the items on the form when it is called:

```
Sub disposer() 'disposes of all the items in the form

        For Each i In Me.Controls

            i.dispose

        Next

End Sub
```

The above, if I'm correct should dispose of everything in the form, however, it appears to only get rid of some items on the form, for example, only half the textboxes, for example.

Comment: How could I create a For loop without knowing how many controls there are, though? I'm calling this sub from where there are either 2 or 20 textboxes, or anything in-between, depending on the page.

Comment: Oh awesome! I didn't know I could count the controls. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the point of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens: you're iterating over the collection of Controls of a Form (or another class that inherits `Control`).

Each time you call `Dispose()` on one of its members, you actively remove it from the collection, so you're modifying the collection you're iterating over.

When you dispose of the first Control, this is removed from the collection and the next Control in the list *takes its place*.
Your loop calls `Enumerator.MoveNext()`, so when you call `Dispose()` again, you're disposing of the element at index 1, which was previously the element at index 2.
The element which was at index 1, now at index 0, is skipped.
This process goes on, the result is that you're disposing of half of the Controls in the collection.

You can test it with:

```
For Each ctrl As Control In Me.Controls
    ctrl.Dispose()
    Console.WriteLine(Me.Controls.Count)
Next
```

You'll see that the final count is half the measure of the initial count: half of the Controls are still very much alive.

You can use a backwards `For` loop (from `[Collection].Count - 1` to `0`), starting from the top of the collection.
In this case, when you dispose of a Control, the Collection is resized from the top so `Enumerator.MovePrevious()` won't skip any element in the collection.

```
For i As Integer = Me.Controls.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    Me.Controls(i).Dispose()
Next
```

You can also use a forward loop and dispose at Index 0. When the element at Index 0 is disposed of, the next in line will take its place at that index, so again you won't skip any. The elements in the collection are constantly moved *towards the bottom* in this case, though, so it's quite a slower process.
If the collection has a small amount of items, you won't notice, but keep it in mind.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To Me.Controls.Count - 1
    Me.Controls(0).Dispose()
Next
```

You can also filter the collection of Controls, to only consider a specific Type.
For example, to dispose of all TextBox Controls child of the Form (or any other class derived from Control):

```
Dim textBoxes = Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox).ToList()
For i As Integer = textBoxes.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    textBoxes(i).Dispose()
Next
```