Disposing of controls only disposes half of the controls I'm targeting
    For Each cntrl As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf cntrl Is Label And cntrl.Name Like "lblPosition_*" Then
            cntrl.Dispose()
        End If
    Next

When I use the above code, it only disposes of half (exactly) of the controls I'm targeting.  If I put a count in there to count the controls, it results in an accurate count, but as soon as I put the dispose() in, I only get about half of the controls disposed.
During testing I added a button that just runs the above code, and each time I press it, it still only gets exactly half of the controls.  (I.e. I'm targeting 64 controls, first press gives me 32, then next gives 16, etc.)
Purpose of this code is to dispose/remove of the targeted controls in an attempt to refresh the controls added at form load.
Solution for others coming here:
    Dim targets = Me.Controls.OfType(Of Label).ToList()
    For i As Integer = targets.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If targets(i).Name Like "lblPosition_*" Then
            targets(i).Dispose()
        End If
    Next


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66498215/visual-basic-form-doesnt-dispose-all-items-when-asked-to Looks like I need to work on my search skills a bit.

yes same problem as other question... you are modifying the collection you are iterating over.

If you wanted to enumerate all controls, the correct option would be Controls.Cast(Of Control)().ToList(). As you're filtering by type using OfType, the cast is being done there now. You can also filter by any other criteria using Where, so your If statement is unnecessary: Controls.OfType(Of Label)().Where(Function(lbl) lblName.StartsWith("lblPosition_")).ToList().

There's no need to switch from a For Each loop to a For loop. The original problem was occurring because disposing a control removes it from the Controls collection of its parent. That's why the collection was being modified. If you create a separate array or collection and enumerate that, it won't be affected by calling Dispose on the controls, so a For Each loop is fine in that case.
